# MobaxTerm Com port settings

Tags: serial-port, mobaxterm

I want to establish a connection with my COM Port but the settings are different. I want to turn on Local echo as well as Newline with Enter.
How can these settings be changed in MobaXterm.

Please help I can't find it anywhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you right click on the terminal and select "Context Menu" > "Change Terminal Settings" then you can set local echo to "Force On" as well as other settings like CR with LF etc.

EDIT: See screenshot of a terminal for how to get to the "Change Terminal Settings" screen.

[image: Right Click/Context menu to access terminal settings]

[image: Terminal settings window showing the "Local Echo" settings]

Comment: No there is no possibility to go into context menu.

Comment: Hi! Please see my edit for a picture of what I mean

Comment: That is what I was looking for, but changing those didn't make any difference to. I am still using the other tool. But thank you that is good.

Comment: I would like to add you must not have set "Past using right click" feature in the terminal setting

Answer (score 0):

If the context menu doesn't appear, then first disable "Paste using right-click" in Settings...Configuration...Terminal

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30596393)

Comment: To be fair, this does partially answer the question. The issue is that, if "Paste using right-click" is enabled, there is no way to get to the context menu, and no indication that a context menu even exists. Following these steps to turn off this option will allow you to then follow the steps provided in the other answer to turn on the echo option.